# Removing unused DLL references in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-extensions

I know that this question has been asked before over the years and that there are extensions out there that can remove unused DLL references, but none of those seem to be compatible with Visual Studio 2013. I also understand that VS 2013 is still pretty new and that some extensions haven't been updated yet, but short of shelling out a good chunk of change for `ReSharper`, are there any VS 2013-compatible extensions out there that can remove unused DLL references from my projects? Or are there other tools/methods of removing references that can get the job done, preferably for free (and not trial-based)?

If there's nothing that fits the bill, having to do it by hand isn't a huge problem by any means; I was just curious as to what's currently available for VS 2013 or what may be upcoming.

(Note that I'm not talking about removing `using` statements; `CodeMaid` already takes care of that.)

Comment: Pretty hard to see the point of an extension like that, the handful of milliseconds in compile time improvement is very hard to observe in practice.  Just do an occasional scan yourself, look at the assembly manifest with ildasm.exe and compare the .assembly directives against the references list.  Once a month is plenty often enough.  Or just write the code yourself.

Comment: I'm curious why is it so crucial for you? Compiler won't add unused references to the assembly manifest...

Comment: It's not crucial by any means. At the time I made this post I was more curious than anything else.

Comment: A valid question. I inherited a solution with 166 projects. They have so many intertwined references that I am really lost. I have to use a tool. Any luck on finding an extension?

Answer (score 1):

There is an extension called [ResloveRU](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/fe96c042-9a83-4fa2-921d-6b09aa044315) that worked for me in VS 2013. But apparently it didn't work well for some people (see the reviews). Back up your project and good luck.

Comment: Wish CodeMaid would do this so i don't have to install a million extensions. Its already a decent alternative to ReSharper